# Youtube API get user videos by tag

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api

I'm having issues while trying to get videos from certain user.

**Situations while trying to retrieve videos from `edransgosocial`**

---

**how:** `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?alt=json&author=edransgosocial`
**getting:** 7 instead of all 9 videos

---

**how:** `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?category=webinar&alt=json&author=edransgosocial`

**getting:** I double checked this: only one video has the `webinar` tag, but 5 videos appears in the response

---

**how:** `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?category=screencast&alt=json&author=edransgosocial`

**getting:** similar, there are two videos with the `screencast` tag but only one is being retrieved

---

**how:** `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat}webinar|screencast?alt=json&safeSearch=none&author=edransgosocial`

**getting:** 25 videos! there are only 9 belonging to that user!

---

I'm trying also with http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html but I always get the same results, this means that my queries are fine (or at least the ones in the demo page are as wrong as mines). My final goal is to retrieve all videos from `edransgosocial` with the `webinar` and `screencast` tag. There should be only 3 videos.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an ongoing issue with the API, and those queries *should* normally work as you'd expect.

Please see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4247